# Trigger Azure pipelines in a specific order

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops

My team is responsible for 10 microservices and it would be useful to have a single pipeline that triggers their individual CI/CD pipelines.

I know it is possible to use pipeline triggers, like

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: MasterPipeline
    source: DeployAllMicroservices
    trigger: true
```

and I can add this to the pipelines and create a very simple `DeployAllMicroservices` pipeline. This works, but the pipelines will be triggered in a random order.

The thing is, two services need to be rolled out first before the other 8 can be deployed. Is there a way to first trigger pipeline `A & B`, where pipelines `C-J` are triggered after their completion?

---

Something else I've tried is to load the pipeline files `A.yml`, `B.yml` as templates from the master pipeline.

```
steps:
  - template: /CmcBs/Pipelines/A.yml
  - template: /CmcBs/Pipelines/B.yml
```

but that doesn't work with full-fledged pipelines (starting with `trigger`, `pool`, `parameters`, *et cetera*).

Comment: Hi Casper Dijkstra; can I ask what problems you had using templates in fully-fledge pipelines? That approach *should* work for your kind of situation.

Comment: @VinceBowdren the full templates cannot be parsed when referencing a template. As far as I'm aware, it can only contain jobs, steps and task.

Comment: Ah, I see; you're trying to call an entire pipeline file as a template; no, that won't work. I've tweaked the wording of your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Currently DevOps does not support multiple pipelines as the triggering pipeline of one pipeline at the same time.

There is a workaround you can refer to:

1. Set pipelineA as the triggering pipeline of the pipelineB.
2. Set pipelineB as the triggering pipeline of the other pipelines(pipelines c-j).

For more info about the triggering pipeline, please see [Trigger one pipeline after another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use stages in order to execute first pipeline A,B and then C to J.

[image: pipeline-stages]

An example .yml for this approach would be the below.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: FirstBatch
  displayName: Build First Batch
  jobs:
  - job: pipelineA
    displayName: Build pipelineA
    steps:
    - script: echo pipelineA
      displayName: pipelineA

  - job: pipelineB
    displayName: Build pipelineB
    steps:
    - script: echo pipelineB
      displayName:  pipelineB


- stage: SecondBatch
  displayName: Build Second Batch
  jobs:
  - job: pipelineC 
    displayName: Build pipelineC
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: echo Build pipelineC
      displayName: Build pipelineC

  - job: pipelineD
    displayName: Build pipelineD
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: echo Build pipelineD
      displayName: Build pipelineD
  
  - job: pipelineE
    displayName: Build pipelineE
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: echo Build pipelineE
      displayName: Build pipelineE
```

The drawback of this approach would be to have a single pipeline and not separated pipelines for your microservices. In order to decouple more this solution you could use templates.